# A question on special relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

Imagine yourself inside a moving spaceship at velocity v(non zero velocity)
Now imagine yourself holding a glass in your hand and you drop it. Now say after 5 sec the glass hits the floor and breaks. For an observer inside the spaceship who drops the glass, will break after 5 sec. Right?
Now consider another observer outside the spaceship who is looking at the observer inside the spaceship. As soon as the person inside spaceship drops the glass, after 5 sec it will break for one inside the spaceship but the one outside spaceship will see the time running slow inside the spaceship so glass is not broken for him yet.
How is it possible that at the same time I have same glass being broken and not broken?

Comment: A more technical answer would be that there is a single point in space*time* at which the glass is broken, the problem is not that this point isn't well-defined, it is simply that the two observers have *labelled* the points of spacetime differently and so (in particular) they disagree on the "time" label of the point at which the glass breaks.

Comment: Time is relative. This is fundamental to the concept of special relativity.

Comment: Probably the most important thing to remember while you are trying to get your head round SR, is that _it does not change reality_!  What _happens_ (to glasses, bombs, ladders etc.) is _never_ observer dependent.  If your speculations or calculations say otherwise, they are _wrong_.  Remember, this thing has been in use for over a century now, it works!

Answer (score 4):

"The same time" (as stated in your answer) does not exist. There is no absolute time (the same time) against which all other times are measured. All times are relative. The time in the spaceship is measured in the frame of the spaceship, the time of the person outside the rocket (who sees the glass falling slowly) is measured in his/her frame. This is exactly what relativity is about.

In the context of your rocket and falling glass this means that *you* see the glass falling in 5 seconds, in the spaceship the glass will smash on the floor (if gravity is present) in less time, dependent on the velocity of the ship. The time that is seen in the spaceship is called the proper time for the glass to fall. This is the time it takes for a happening as seen in a stationary frame. This time is the shortest time.

Comment: It might be a little clearer to the OP to mention that there is no absolute notion of *simultaneity*. No two inertial observers in different frames will agree on events being simultaneous.

Comment: The 'same time' I refer in my question actually means that after 5 seconds have passed the glass is broken for me, whereas during the same time interval i.e after 5 seconds I see the glass still in the air from outside. I guess you understand me and I don't understand why same time here doesn't exist at all . Please answer my question in terms of the thought experiment that I had done

Comment: Simply, in the spaceship you see the glass broken after 5 sec. From the other inertial frame the information that the glass broke hasn't arrived yet to you because, as I wrote in my answer below, you can't propagate informations at a velocity bigger than $c$. So you see the glass still intact

Comment: @Philip Aren't the events of the falling glass simultaneous for both the person in the rest frame and the person in the rocket? The falling glass may be seen later for the person at rest, but the falling glass itself is just a sequence of events. I don't see what simultaneity has to do with this question.

Comment: @HitmanReborn The time dilation doesn't occur because light from the glass has to reach the moving observer, this effect happens regardless of where they are relative to it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mixed up idea of what time dilation means. The glass breaks when it breaks- it is not broken in one frame and unbroken in another. The two observers simply disagree on how long it took to fall and what time it was when it hit the ground.

From the point of view of the clumsy person on the moving spaceship who dropped the glass, the fall started at time ts, say, and finished (ie the glass broke) at time tf, where the difference between the two was five seconds as measured by the clocks on the ship.

From the point of view of the stationary observer outside, the fall began at t's and finished at t'f, where the difference was more than five seconds. So the stationary observer thinks the fall takes longer than the moving one.

However, you must realise that tf and t'f are the exact same instant in time. It is simply that the two observers use a different value of their time coordinate to label it.

Almost all these puzzles have simple spatial analogies. If you imagine that you and I each have a map of a city centred on some landmark, but your map has a grid that is tilted compared with mine. I walk 200 metres from the landmark along my x axis, so my y coordinate remains zero. On your grid, which is rotated compared with main, I will have walked less than 200m in your x direction, and more than zero in your y direction. My position remains my position, it is just that you and I are using different coordinates to label it.

That is directly analogous to the breaking glass. The person on the ship uses one value of t to label the instant it happens, while the stationary person uses another value of t because the time axes of the two observers are tilted- just as the tilting of the x axes of the two maps led us to use different values of x to record my position on our respective maps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the principles of special relativity states that the speed of light in vacuum is the same for all inertial frames of reference and that it does not depend on the relative motion of the source. Equivalently: in every inertial reference system there is a limiting speed for the propagation of physical entities (signals, particles).
One of the most important consequences is the concept of: "Relativity of Simultaneity". In classical mechanics time is absolute and two events are simultaneous if they occur at the same time and Galileo's transformations ensure that this is independent of the inetial observer.
In SR, simultaneity becomes relativity i.e. simultaneous events for one observer may not be simultaneous for another; just like in your case. Time is no longer an absolute quantity precisely because of this principle and the fact that you are in motion with respect to an observer. Time flows differently for the two observers. There is no point in talking about the fact that the glass is broken and at the same time intact. It is something that depends on the reference system.
The information of the glass broken doesn't arrive to you istantely because informations propagate with a velocity $v$ different from $\infty$. This is the point that makes you understand Special Relativity.

Comment: Marco Ocram, I didn't understand why you mentioned in the answer that tf and t'f are the same instant in time? I would like you to elaborate that point.

Comment: @RAHUL I think it's the other answer for you comment.